# grub not adding newly installed kernel to list

Tags: kernel, grub

I'm on an Arch system with LUKS and BRTFS and I recently installed `linux-zen`, but it doesn't show up anywhere in grub. I've tried `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`, but it does nothing, even though it says it `found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-linux-zen`.
The full output of grub-mkconfig is below:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found theme: /boot/grub/themes/fallout-grub-theme/theme.txt
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-linux-zen
Found initrd image: /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-linux-zen.img
Found fallback initrd image(s) in /boot:  intel-ucode.img initramfs-linux-zen-fallback.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-linux-lqx
Found initrd image: /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-linux-lqx.img
Found fallback initrd image(s) in /boot:  intel-ucode.img initramfs-linux-lqx-fallback.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-linux
Found initrd image: /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-linux.img
Found fallback initrd image(s) in /boot:  intel-ucode.img initramfs-linux-fallback.img
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
Detecting snapshots ...
No snapshots found.
If you think an error has occurred, please file a bug report at "https://github.com/Antynea/grub-btrfs"
Unmount /tmp/grub-btrfs.dRwuoNA1Do .. Success
done
```

Here is my `/etc/default/grub`

```
# GRUB boot loader configuration

GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="5"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="Arch"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="loglevel=3 quiet nvidia-drm.modset=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

#START ME STUFF
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU="y"
GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"
#END ME STUFF
# Preload both GPT and MBR modules so that they are not missed
GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="part_gpt part_msdos"

# Uncomment to enable booting from LUKS encrypted devices
GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK="y"

# Set to 'countdown' or 'hidden' to change timeout behavior,
# press ESC key to display menu.
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="menu"

# Uncomment to use basic console
#GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT="console"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal
#GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `videoinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE="auto"

# Uncomment to allow the kernel use the same resolution used by grub
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX="keep"

# Uncomment if you want GRUB to pass to the Linux kernel the old parameter
# format "root=/dev/xxx" instead of "root=/dev/disk/by-uuid/xxx"
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment and set to the desired menu colors.  Used by normal and wallpaper
# modes only.  Entries specified as foreground/background.
#GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="light-blue/black"
#GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT="light-cyan/blue"

# Uncomment one of them for the gfx desired, a image background or a gfxtheme
#GRUB_BACKGROUND="/path/to/wallpaper"
GRUB_THEME="/boot/grub/themes/fallout-grub-theme/theme.txt"

# Uncomment to get a beep at GRUB start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

# Uncomment to make GRUB remember the last selection. This requires
# setting 'GRUB_DEFAULT=saved' above.
#GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"

# Uncomment to disable submenus in boot menu
#GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU="y"

# Probing for other operating systems is disabled for security reasons. Read
# documentation on GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER, if still want to enable this
# functionality install os-prober and uncomment to detect and include other
# operating systems.
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="false"

GRUB_THEME="/boot/grub/themes/fallout-grub-theme/theme.txt"
```

The other weird part is that my `/boot/grub` contains references to the zen kernel but that is not reflected in startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my issue was the presence of `systemd-boot`. A simple `sudo bootctl remove` got me into grub, although there were some issues with my root device's UUID being set wrong, so be careful before uninstalling your bootloader.